# VB 2008 program crash with System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: vb.net, debugging, crash

I have a huge program, written in VB 2008, that involves lot of homemade DLL's, socket communication, multi-threading, etc.

Sometimes, out of nowhere, the program crash with the following details in the Event Viewer:
CLR20r3 
   Not available 
   0 
   CMS.exe 
   1.0.0.0 
   5177cc90 
   mscorlib 
   2.0.0.0 
   4a275af7 
   3440 
   10 
   System.ObjectDisposedException

I did my homework to try to locate the problem but I can't pinpoint exactly where it might be (there is hundreads of thousands of lines of code in this assembly). I put a Handler to catch any UnHandledException in the main() but it doesn't seems to fire at all.

my question is, how can I debug this outside VS? The software is installed on a production industrial PC in our client's warehouse, so we can't install VS for obvious reasons.

any hints would be really appreciate.

thanks for your precious time and help

Comment: My crystal balls says that you wrote an event handler for Application.UnhandledException.  Wrong one, you need AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.  Pretty pointless to make us guess at this btw, always post a snippet.

Comment: Public Sub main()

        Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler
....

Private Sub MyHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
        m_eLog.WriteEntry("X-Actim UnHandledException: " & e.ToString)
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling [System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) and [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) do the trick in 80% of case (sadly, some errors like COM error would not be caught).

In such events you can for example dump to a Log file the Exception message and Exception StackTrace.
If you provide the pdb files with your Application, you will be able to see the Line number in the StackTrace, providing a good way to debug it.

Comment: thanks for the reply

Does the AppDomain.UnhandledException handler also caught an exception that could happen in a DLL in reference? There is about 50 DLL loaded by the software at startup. I did put the handler in the main() which is obviously the entry point of the whole solution.

How can I dump the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Yes. It does catch any exception caught by your application or any dynamic library loaded (NB: COM components are not handled directly by your application). Assuming "ex" is you Exception, you should log ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.Source and the same things for ex.InnerException (if there are multiple exceptions)

Comment: What I don't understand is my exception handler is NEVER executed. Only trace I have from the Event Viewer is the application has crashed. So do you have an idea why my handler is never triggered?? I thought that maybe the exception was coming from one of the many DLL's loaded (all .Net assemblies), but you say it should catch them anyway. I'm really confused